# How Can I optimize my FTP Download using foreach() and ftpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

Here is the code that I am using, it will work but the ftp portion of the application is taking around 5 minutes.

The files them selves are not too big, but I would like to optimize the application and I feel like this is the best place to start.

What I try to do is download the 4 particular files.

here are the file sizes:

1 - ~48mb 
2 - ~856k
3 - ~25mb
4 - ~49mb

```
// BEGIN FTP 
                WebClient request = new WebClient();
                request.Credentials =
                       new NetworkCredential(this.userNameRTF.Text,
                                                this.passRTF.Text);


                string[] ftpFile = new string[4];
                ftpFile[0] = "1";
                ftpFile[1] = "2";
                ftpFile[2] = "3";
                ftpFile[3] = "4"; 


                foreach(string s in ftpFile) 
                {
                    string ftpFileName = s;                        


                    byte[] fileData =
                            request.DownloadData(this.ftpHost
                                                   + this.ftpPath.Text + ftpFileName);                  

                    FileStream file =
                        File.Create(@"\\nas03\customerftp\" + custName.Text + @"\" + ftpFileName);

                    file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);

                    file.Close(); 
                }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you put in any tracing code to really see which lines are the problem in terms of performance.  You can easily use the StopWatch class to help you with this.

Comment: I'm not really sure what a tracing code is? I've been teaching myself so I'm sure I'm not up on everything Visual studio has to offer....

Comment: Please also note that some FTP server configuration can only accept a single connection from a client IP, so any trick of parallel downloading will fail in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell where your files are coming from, with which bandwith, and where they are going with which bandwith. From the few lines of code it doesn't seem that there's any obvious bottleneck, other than your internet connection itself. Simply calculate how much data can be downloaded using your bandwith.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just handle these using the API:

```
WebClient request = new WebClient();
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.userNameRTF.Text,
                                            this.passRTF.Text);

string[] ftpFiles = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
var tasks = ftpFiles.Select(f => request.DownloadFileTaskAsync(
                         this.ftpHost + this.ftpPath.Text + ftpFileName,
                         @"\\nas03\customerftp\" + custName.Text + @"\" + ftpFileName));

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

In addition to simplifying the code, this will download and save the files concurrently.

Note that you can make this an asynchronous method (in .NET 4.5/C# 5) by switching the last line to:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

---

Given that you're using .NET 4, you could use the older `DownloadFileAsync` method:

```
WebClient request = new WebClient();
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.userNameRTF.Text,
                                            this.passRTF.Text);

var ftpFiles = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
var ce = new CountdownEvent(ftpFiles.Length);

request.DownloadFileCompleted += (o,e) => ce.Signal();

foreach(var file in ftpFiles)
    request.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(this.ftpHost + this.ftpPath.Text + ftpFileName),
                         @"\\nas03\customerftp\" + custName.Text + @"\" + ftpFileName));

ce.Wait();
```

Comment: Sorry iam quite beginner at c#, I'm doing the best I can to teach myself but somethings escape me. When I try to use your example I get that 'System.net.WebClient' does not contain a reference for 'DownloadFileTaskAsync'. i do have 'using System.Net' So I think I have the right setup, of course Im probably missing something very obvious.

Comment: @MitchellHamann That's a .NET 4.5 method - what framework version are you using?

Comment: I had no idea how to find that until now, looks like .Net 4.0 Im not sure any of our production servers are using .NET 4.5.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you on this, I noticed one more issues with the CountDownEvent, it sates "the type or namespace could not be found". I did Add using System.Threading in at the top. Not sure what else I would be missing

Comment: @MitchellHamann It's `CountdownEvent` (lower case D): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx

Comment: I think there is an issue on your code. You just used LINQ to call "DownloadFileTaskAsync" but your lambda expression don't use your "f" which is actually representing the "ftpFilename" of the iteration. It should be :

var tasks = ftpFiles.Select(f => request.DownloadFileTaskAsync(
                         this.ftpHost + this.ftpPath.Text + f,
                         @"\\nas03\customerftp\" + custName.Text + @"\" + f));